# Getting access to my main screen/desktop in phone

Tags: java, android

I would like to make customizer app something like "apex laucher". I was wonder how can I get my main screen/desktop content on my phone, what permission should I declare and so on.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this on Android's SE site.

Comment: For Example I would like to change gravity on my android device that everything would be upside down or making new design of my current look of icon. Do you get it now ?

Comment: Your options without modifying and rebuilding the source of Android itself are a bit limited.  There are a number of APIs to customize a few fairly trivial parameters, and you can do a lot more in apps you build from source (potentially including your own homescreen launcher), but most system-wide things are out of reach on a secured consumer device.